# HTML - file upload form does not work with iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, upload

Uploading files on the IPad is not possible because "Choose file" is grayed out. Is there a workaround to upload files in a iPad browser. I'm using the current chrome for iPad.

my upload code:

```
    document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", function ( e ){...});
```

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Ios6? Ios5?  The file input element is supported on ios6, but not 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a workaround to upload files, it is simply not builded in the software... I've never seen a site were it was working. (only in apps)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3863546?start=0&tstart=0 is saying the same thing...

Comment: Simply upgrade to iOS6, which supports the file input element, and, therefore, uploading content via Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the upload file dialog since iOS6, but it only provides access to photos. The best methods of getting a file upload working to your website are:

1. Create an app that can take file attachments from email and then push them to your website
2. Setup a special email address users can forward attachments to which then puts those into their account (this method is called piping)

This does however assume that the files needing to be uploaded are sitting in the user's mailbox.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Good answer!